# Existence of well-order on an arbitrary infinite set $X$ without a largest element

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

I've already asked a similar question yesterday (is there a well-order such that $X$ has a largest element). Can one prove the existence of a well-order on an infinite set $X$ such that $\forall x \in X \exists y \in X: x \leq y$?

Comment: Every ordering trivially satisfies your condition. Did you mean $x<y$?

Comment: Yes.  Every linear order for a finite set has a maximum.